# How to format html elements in one line in SCSS file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

How do I format the html element in scss to be one line?

[image]

I am using Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using visual studio code, try this extension

[Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Comment: Which option in Prettier to do this format?

Answer (score 1):

Go to File, Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts and search for Join Lines. Set up a keybind that you like and then go to your code. Select all your elements then press that keybind. It should be in one line!

Comment: Not so sure what is keybind and how it works?

Comment: Keybinding is when you bind a key to a command, so when you press that key/keys it will execute the command that you tell it, in this case "Join Lines". Follow the instructions I wrote, after you find "Join Lines" in the options, click on the pencil that is on the left most side of the line and then it will ask you to press a key/keys to keybind. Do that and then what you have to do is select the lines you want to make into 1 (just highlight them) and then press that keybind.